# How to automate keypress event on web page

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, television

I am trying to test keyboard input on a TV display. I can't figure out how to get Selenium web driver to work and I don't want to bring in JQuery as a dependency. Is there a way to automate keypresses in Javascript without JQuery/Selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
let elem = document.getElementById('#myInput');
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
elem.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'a'}));
```

And possibly use it with `.setTimeout()`?

Comment: That almost works but doesn't. I'm running a React app on my TV and the button I'm trying to click is managed by a react-hotkeys container which should trigger based on keyboard input but it doesn't. :(

Comment: document.activeElement
<button tabindex=​"-1" type=​"button" class=​"ActionButton btn btn-default">​Set A Reminder​</button>​
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{code:'Enter', keyCode: 13, charCode: 13, which: 13, bubbles: true, cancelBubble: false}));
true

Comment: I finally got this to work! I was misunderstanding how focus was leaving my element when I ran the code in the chrome dev tools.